# android studio - how to get a specific String from <script> html (from json)

Tags: android, html, android-studio, httpresponse

I have an html script as a result of response http ruquest.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://blablabla">
<script>
    logged_user = false;
    var static_id_cdn = 7;
    var html5player = new HTML5Player('html5video', '41030861');
    if (html5player) {
        html5player.setVideoTitle('Title here');
        html5player.setSponsors(false);
        html5player.setVideoUrlLow('https://blablabla');
        html5player.setVideoUrlHigh('https://blablabla');
        html5player.setVideoHLS('https://blablabla');
        html5player.setThumbUrl('https://blablabla');
        html5player.setThumbUrl169('https://blablabla');
        html5player.setRelated(video_related);
        html5player.setThumbSlide('https://blablabla');
        html5player.setThumbSlideBig('https://blablabla');
        html5player.setThumbSlideMinute('blablabla');
        html5player.setIdCDN('3');
        html5player.setIdCdnHLS('2');
        html5player.setFakePlayer(false);
        html5player.setDesktopiew(true);
      html5player.setSeekBarColor('#de2600');
        html5player.setUploaderName('mmm100');
        html5player.setVideoURL('/video41030861/title');
        html5player.setStaticDomain('static.blablabla.com');
        html5player.setHttps();
        html5player.setCanUseHttps();
        document.getElementById('html5video').style.minHeight = '';
        html5player.initPlayer();
   }

</script>
```

How do I want to take a specific string that is only 'html5player.setVideoHLS ('https://blablabla)' using java?

Comment: So you want to scrap that page?

Comment: put the HTML code into the `String`, find the index of `html5player.setVideoHLS('`, add the length of it, find the index of the next `')`, and use `String.subString()` method to cut the url out

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko cool